# How to test that a function only accepts a certain type?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I want to ensure that `twist_data` only gets a list of integers as an argument, and add a unit test.

```
 def twist_data(n):
     n=list(n)
     a=[]
     b=[]
     for i in n:
         if i<=0:
             a.append(i)
         if i>0:
             b.append(i)
     n=[len(a),sum(b)]
     return n


 gum=[2,4,5,-6,-7,]
 print (twist_data (gum))
```

Comment: Is your question how can you make sure that the function only completes if `n` is a list?

Comment: What I mean is that. I want to be able to test in the pyhonic way that the argument is a list of integers. So that if someone calls the function for a dict or tuple, it will give him a customized error message. and if he calls it for a list whose elements are strings , then it will also give him a customized error message

Comment: I don't think there is a pythonic way to test what you're asking about, because working only with lists (when any iterable object would do) is not pythonic. Similarly, your code will already fail if there's a value in `n` that can't be compared with an integer (which will include strings if you're using Python 3, where comparison operators like `<=` don't work between arbitrary types).

Comment: So what do I do. I tried this:

Comment: clarify title, reword question based on clarifying comments from OP

Answer (score 0):

```
def all_ints(numbers):
    return all(isinstance(number, int) for number in numbers)


def validate_list(numbers):
    return all((isinstance(numbers, list), all_ints(numbers))


def twist_data(numbers):
    if not validate_list(numbers):
        raise TypeError('"numbers" must be of type "list", where all elements integers')
    positives, negatives = [], []
    for number in numbers:
        if number <= 0:
            negatives.append(number)
        if i > 0:
            positives.append(number)
    return [len(negatives), sum(positives)]
```

While not generally Pythonic to do explicit type checking sometimes it's unavoidable. This is a pretty straight forward way to do so. However it's easier to ask for forgiveness than to ask for permission so this is another possibility:

```
def twist_data(numbers):
    positives, negatives = [], []
    try:
        for number in numbers:
            if number <= 0:
                negatives.append(number)
            if i > 0:
                positives.append(number)
        return [len(negatives), sum(positives)]
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError('"numbers" must be of type "list", where all elements integers')
```

Here a `TypeError` is raised if you try to do a comparison between non-comparable types. You can then catch the exception and reraise with your own message.

Also do try to avoid single letter variable names. It'll be much easier to keep track of what's going on.